# Jupyter notebook truncates very large FITS file

Tags: jupyter, large-data, large-files, astronomy, fits

When I try importing the [mastar-goodspec-v3_1_1-v1_7_7.fits](https://dr17.sdss.org/mastar/spectrum/search) file (about 7 GB) on a Jupyter notebook, I get a warning saying that only x GB were imported. Unsurprisingly, when I try to do anything this data, I recieve a "unsufficient buffer size" error, which is frequent with corrupted files.

I have read that FITS files were not adequate for large file sizes and that I should convert it to another format such as HDF. I tried doing this inside the Jupyter notebook, as well as on cmd with a module called [fits2hdf](https://fits2hdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - To no avail in both cases, as the file was already truncated as I was converting it.

In my documents, the file does contain 7 GB so the original download is not to blame.

I would like to be recommended a way to stop the file from being truncated. I do not need all 7GB worth of rows in this file, so if it's possible to reduce its number of rows before importing it to Jupyter, that would work for me too.

Comment: "In my documents, the file does contain 7 GB" yes, but 7GB of *what*? No guarantee there's anything useful there.  "When I try importing"--what exactly did you try? Also what happened when you used fits2hdf? For what it's worth Jupyter very likely has nothing to do with this either.